# placing equation numbering before right curly bracket

Tags: equations

Is there a way to shift the bracket such that it is after the equation numbering. For the moment, the numbers appear after the curly bracket

```
 \begin{subequations}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace}]{align}
      & \frac{1}{2}(ab + ba) =  a \cdot b\\
      &\frac{1}{2}(ab - ba) =  a \wedge b
    \end{empheq}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{align} 
      \implies ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b
    \end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: This question would be more obvious if you either showed the output of the code or explained in words *why* you want the numbers inside the bracket.  Although this is now demonstrated by the answer, and the reason is obvious, from what you have posted, one might actually have to compile to see what is wanted, and that might discourage potential helpers.